# Would the √2 be an infinitely reducible fraction if written as one?

Tags: radicals, infinity, ratio

As the questions states, would the $\sqrt{2}$ be an infinitely reducible fraction if written as one?

Comment: That's usually the conclusion when trying to prove it's irrational, yes.

Comment: Note that if $\sqrt{2}$ could be written as a ratio of integers, then that ratio would be $\frac{59}{42}$.

Comment: If $\sqrt2$ were written as a fraction, then that fraction would be $\frac01$. And $-\frac13$. And it would also be "infinitely reducible". And it would also not be a fraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a standard way to prove that $\sqrt{2}$ is not rational: if it were, then we can 'infinitely reduce' it as follows:

That is, assuming: $\sqrt{2} = \frac{p}{q}$ where $p$ and $q$ are whole numbers

we get: $2 = \frac{p^2}{q^2}$

and thus: $2q^2 = p^2$

and thus $p^2$ is even

and thus $p$ is even. Say $p = 2k$ for some whole number $k$

So then $2q^2 = (2k)^2 = 4k^2$

So $q^2 = 2k^2$

So $q^2$ is even

So $q$ is even. Say $q = 2m$ for some whole number $m$

And thus we can reduce:

$\sqrt{2} = \frac{p}{q} = \frac{2k}{2m} = \frac{m}{n}$

... and using the exact same reasoning, we can reduce *that* fraction as well! ... and thus it becomes 'infinitely reducible'.

But of course, rational numbers are *not* infinitely reducible like this: given that $q$ is a whole number, we can't keep dividing it by two, for that would mean that there are an infinite number of positive numbers smaller than $q$, which is impossible.

Hence, $\sqrt{2}$ cannot be a rational number.

This proof is an example of an 'infinite descent' proof, which basically combines a proof by strong induction and a proof by contradiction.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the detailed explanation!